# Manipulating the HttpSession in a JSF ViewHandlerWrapper doesn't work

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

In a ViewHandlerWrapper-implementation I have following code:

```
public void renderView(FacesContext context, UIViewRoot viewToRender) throws IOException, FacesException {
    final String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    httpSession.setAttribute("expectedToken", token);

    getWrapped().renderView(context, viewToRender);
}
```

As you can see, I want to add a UUID to the Session. Following the debugger I can see that the attribute stays on the Session until the entire request-response cycle of the servlet container is complete. However, at the next invocation the "expectedToken" attribute is null.

Before going "old school" (fetching the HttpSession) I tried to manipulate a value object on the session, which rendered the same result. The change was dismissed.

Is this *not* supposed to work (after all, the response is not committed when renderView is invoked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather use the JSF-provided [`ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSessionMap%28%29). This is in turn transparently backed by the HTTP session.

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.getSessionMap().put("key", "value");
```

A hint for the future, whenever you need to haul the raw Servlet API from under the JSF hoods, ask yourself twice: Am I doing it the right way? Isn't there a JSF-ish way? In almost all cases there is. If in vain, just ask here :)

Comment: Well, as I said "before going old school" I did try it the JSF-way... Which didn't work either :(

Comment: Apparently the session has not been maintained for the subsequent request. This can have a lot of causes, the important being: 1) domain has changed, 2) context has changed, 3) client doesn't support cookies, 4) session was programmatically invalidated.

Comment: Turns out that all versions presented here and which I tested before were OK and worked. The problem is that I read the session values at the wrong point in time, always rendering "NULL" as a result. Apperantely it has to be read before RENDER_RESPONSE and after UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES. I will accept both answers because you guys made me confident that it's not wrong to add something to the session in a ViewHandler.

Comment: Interesting. Haven't seen that before. What JSF impl/version exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the session without recreation

```
HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```